# can't push file using gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

I have one git server over ubuntu machine, I have installed gitolite and also clone gitolite-admin repo, now the problem is I cant push or pull other repos excluding gitolite-admin and testing provided by gitolite.

```
ADMIN@CSO49-PC MINGW64 /e/heena/heena/gitolite-admin (master)
$ git clone git@192.168.0.106:gitolite-admin
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
remote: Counting objects: 6, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

ADMIN@CSO49-PC MINGW64 /e/heena/heena/gitolite-admin (master)
$ git push git@192.168.0.106:gitolite-admin
Everything up-to-date

ADMIN@CSO49-PC MINGW64 /e/heena/heena/gitolite-admin (master)
$ git push git@192.168.0.106:testing.git
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 731 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 6 (delta 0)
To git@192.168.0.106:testing.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master

ADMIN@CSO49-PC MINGW64 /e/heena/heena/gitolite-admin (master)
$ git push git@192.168.0.106:cicd.git
FATAL: W any cicd admin DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: As it says, make sure you didn't misspelled the repo name and you have the correct access rights for it. From your description I would say the `cicd.git` repo doesn't exist. A remote repository must already exist in order to push to it and there is no way to create it using local commands. You have to create it on the remote server (using the command line in a remote session or the web interface, if the remote server provides one.)

Comment: Thanks axiac, but its working now, there were some minor mistake but it has solved now

Comment: @HeenaPatel can you post below as an answer what you did to fix those errors?

Comment: I have posted answer , you should check it

Answer (score 1):

this is quite simple.

1.add new repo in gitolite file located in conf folder in gitolite-admin repo.
2. add it using git command bash, commit it and push it over git server 
3. now fire regular command of git with reference to newly created repo.

following are the steps perform by me on client side

To add new repo, heena

```
 repo gitolite-admin
RW+     =   admin

repo testing
RW+     =   @all

**repo heena
RW+     =   @all**

 ADMIN@CSO49-PC MINGW64 /e/heena/heena/gitolite-admin (master)
 $ cd conf

 ADMIN@CSO49-PC MINGW64 /e/heena/heena/gitolite-admin/conf (master)
 $ git add gitolite.conf

 ADMIN@CSO49-PC MINGW64 /e/heena/heena/gitolite-admin/conf (master)
 $ git commit -m"done" gitolite.conf
 [master 91ce8e2] done
  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

 ADMIN@CSO49-PC MINGW64 /e/heena/heena/gitolite-admin/conf (master)
 $ git push git@192.168.0.106:gitolite-admin
 Counting objects: 4, done.
 Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
 Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
 Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 363 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
 Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Initialized empty Git repository in /home/git/repositories/heena.git/
```

To git@192.168.0.106:gitolite-admin
   8fb8572..91ce8e2  master -> master

its created new repo on my git server

now commands to push file into newly created repo heena.git

```
  ADMIN@CSO49-PC MINGW64 /e/heena/heena/cicd (master)
  $ ls
 sample.txt

ADMIN@CSO49-PC MINGW64 /e/heena/heena/cicd (master)
 $ git add sample.txt

ADMIN@CSO49-PC MINGW64 /e/heena/heena/cicd (master)
```

$ git push git@192.168.0.106:heena.git
   Counting objects: 6, done.
   Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
   Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
   Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 467 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
   Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
   To git@192.168.0.106:heena.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master